# Why call 'endOfStream' before play in MSE?

Tags: javascript, media-source

In the MSE example, call endOfstream before play

```
mediaSource.endOfStream();
video.play()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/endOfStream

Do you know why call endOfStream before play?
I thought 'endOfStream' calls when signals the termination of the video.

Thanks!

Comment: "MSE stands for mean-squared error" -- Read the tag and [edit] with the correct tags

Comment: @cricket_007 Note, "MSE" is also [Media Source Extensions™](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/)

Comment: @guest271314 Sure, not here, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mse

Comment: @cricket_007 Interesting. Curious how frequently `mse` tag has been included at a Question to reference Media Source Extenstions?

Comment: @cricket_007 Not sure how to address the matter, if at all. From the link you shared  the present Question does not appear to be an isolated case. Users have determined which is which on their own.

Comment: @guest271314 You probably have enough rep to create a new tag, but here. http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/31877

Comment: @cricket_007 What do you suggest? Housing both under same tag? Are tags case-sensitive?

Comment: @cricket_007 Meta Stack Exchange or Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: @guest271314 Tags are on all SE sites, so main meta? This is getting off-topic :)

Comment: @cricket_007 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290087/disambiguate-mse-tag

Answer (score 2):

`.endOfStream()` is apparently used at `javascript` at Question to update the `duration` of the `HTMLMediaElement` before media playback begins.

[2.4.7 End of stream algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#end-of-stream-algorithm)

> NOTE
>
> This allows the duration to properly reflect the end of the appended
>   media segments. For example, if the duration was explicitly set to 10
>   seconds and only media segments for 0 to 5 seconds were appended
>   before `endOfStream()` was called, then the duration will get updated to
>   5 seconds.